# Sort data in Powershell HTML Output

Tags: sorting, powershell

I've read so much about the sort-object tag in Powershell, but cannot figure out how to implement it as a part of my script.  Right now I have a powershell script that takes xml files and gives me some output.

Column A - gives results of if the user has admin rights by user name
Column B - gives results of if the user has admin rights by asset tag
Column C - basically sums it all up, puts an X if Admin rights are found.

Is there any way to sort column C and just show the ones with an "X" on top?  That way if i'm looking at 100 PCs, all the potential issues are at the top of the report.  Below is the code I have so far

```
# adminAccess.html
$X = "X"
"<th>" + $log.scan.machine + "</th>" | Out-File "adminAccess.html" -Append
if($log.scan.admin.byUsername.hasAdminRights -eq "YES"){
    "<td class='danger'>" + $log.scan.admin.username + " - Has Admin Rights</td>" | Out-File "adminAccess.html" -Append
}else{
    "<td>No Admin Rights</td>" | Out-File "adminAccess.html" -Append
}
if($log.scan.admin.byAssetTag.hasAdminRights -eq "YES"){
    "<td class='danger'>" + $log.scan.admin.assetTag + " - Has Admin Rights</td>" | Out-File "adminAccess.html" -Append
}else{
    "<td>No Admin Rights</td>" | Out-File "adminAccess.html" -Append
}
if ($log.scan.admin.byUsername.hasAdminRights -eq "YES" -Or $log.scan.admin.byAssetTag.hasAdminRights -eq "YES") {
"<td>" + $X + "</td></tr>" | Out-File "adminAccess.html" -Append
}Else{
"<td> </td></tr>" | Out-File "adminAccess.html" -Append
}
```

Comment: Guessing you mean sort it _before_ you export it. Should this that you could make an object array first. Sort that and then for each row build your table. You could just use `ConvertTo-HTML` but you want special formatting.

Comment: I agree with what Matt said. The hard part here is that you don't really say how your data is structured. Do you have an array of XML objects, and your're running `ForEach($Log in $Array)`? Is the `$log.scan.admin` an array? Can you work within PS to setup your formatting and then just use ConvertTo-HTML to output something at the end rather than building the HTML file the hard way?